# Align horizontally 2 figures with minipage (with one figure have a longer caption than the other)

Tags: minipage, includegraphics, subfig

I want to put 2 figures next to each other using `minipage` command. The caption of one of the image is longer than the other and takes seval lines. This has for consequences to disalign the images horizontally. How is possible to realign the 2 images and their corresponding caption (with the longer caption finishing lower than the shorter one)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{example-image-a} % first figure itself
        \caption{first figure}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{example-image-b} % second figure itself
        \caption{second figure blabla, blabla,  blabla, blabla, blabla, blabla, blabla, blabla, blabla, blabla, blabla,}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can do that easily with the `floatrow` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{floatrow}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[11]
\begin{figure}
 \centering
 \renewcommand{\floatrowsep}{\hskip 4em}
\begin{floatrow}
  \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\includegraphics[width=0.40\textwidth]{example-image-a}}% first figure itself
{\caption{first figure}\label{fig-a}}
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\includegraphics[width=0.40\textwidth]{example-image-b}} % second figure itself
    {\caption{second figure blabla, blabla, blabla, blabla, blabla, blabla, blabla, blabla, blabla, blabla, blabla,}\label{fig-b}}
\end{floatrow}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ok I just found the answer:

replace the 2:

```
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
```

by

```
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
```